# Calling function with generic protocol as return type

Tags: swift, swift2

The following example should create concrete objects for abstract protocols.

```
class ClassA<T: FloatingPointType> {}

protocol ProtocolA
{
    typealias T: FloatingPointType
    var value : ClassA<T>? { get set }
}

class ClassImplProtocolA<T: FloatingPointType> : ProtocolA
{
    var value : ClassA<T>? {
        get {
            return nil
        }
        set {
        }
    }
}

class Factory
{
    class func createProtocol<PA: ProtocolA where PA.T: FloatingPointType>() -> PA
    {
        let concreteObject = ClassImplProtocolA<PA.T>()
        let abstractObject = concreteObject as? PA
        return abstractObject!
    }
}
```

Now two questions:
Is it possible to avoid the `as? PA`? 
and how does the syntax look like to call `Factory.createProtocol<...>()`?

Or how do I work around this? All I want is an object of the abstract type `PrtocolA<FloatingPointType>` without exposing `ClassImplProtocolA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you cannot avoid `as? PA` since the return Type is determined by the type inference like this:

```
let prot: ClassImplProtocolA<Double> = Factory.createProtocol()
let prot = Factory.createProtocol() as ClassImplProtocolA<Double>
```

Another issue in this case is that you cannot use `FloatingPointType` as generic type (has `Self` requirements) and you have to use one which conforms to this protocol (like `Double` and `Float`).

In Swift's standard library they use `AnySequence`, `AnyGenerator`,... (generic structs) in order to have an abstract type of a protocol which has `Self` requirements. Unfortunately you cannot make a type `AnyProtocolA<FloatingPointType>` because the generic type itself has `Self` requirements.

Comment: Thanks that helps to understand. So I can create a fund (like `createProtocol` here) in swift that is impossible to call?

Comment: @V1ru8 This `func` can be called as I have shown in the two examples. But why would you make a `func` that is impossible to call? Simply don't implement one.

Comment: I got confused but ok I get it now. The whole thing still looks pretty ugly to see since it is not possible to have two level of abstract generics in a nice way. Calling `createProtocol` without exposing `ClassImplProtocolA` is not really possible like this. Using `AnyGenerator` kinda kills the whole idea of generics and does not help to make the code more readable.

Comment: I'm still confused ;) If I use AnyGenerator in the Factory I can get rid of the `as` ok. Although I don't see a way of 'unwrapping' it and getting it back to a 'ProtocolA' type which is the whole type why I'm doing it. The only option I see to actually fix this is to change `ProtocolA` to a class but I loss the multiple inheritance of protocols which then causes to break the whole idea. Any suggestions on that?